# Easy image rotating gallery

Tags: javascript

I have this image-rotating-script that i cannot get to work in any major browser.
What the JS does is to show a random image on pageload.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- Begin
    var theImages = new Array();

    theImages[0] = 'img/rot/forside/FrontReklame1.jpg';
    theImages[1] = 'img/rot/forside/FrontReklame2.jpg';

    var j = 0;
    var p = theImages.length;
    var preBuffer = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < p; i++){
       preBuffer[i] = new Image()
       preBuffer[i].src = theImages[i]
    };

    var whichImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));
    function showImage(){
    document.write('<img src="'+theImages[whichImage]+'" alt="Se vores hingste!" />')
    };
    //  End -->
    </script>
```

What i use to call the image:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- Begin
    showImage();
//  End -->
</script>
```

This code doesn't show any image live on the net and sometimes it doesn't when i test the page locally?! What am i missing here?

Comment: do you get errors in console? Are you sure the image paths are correct? I also assume that you call the function NOT in the head of the page, right?

Comment: No errors and yes they are. I really can't figure out what is wrong here! But i think that it might be the semicolons, but either combinations of them semicolon-rules found on net isn't making it working either...

Comment: I use "showImage()" in the body of the page! ;)

Comment: I'd alert the value of theImages[whichImage] inside the function to see if it contains the correct value.

Comment: @DarkoRomanov > I'm not really sure what to do. But i added this in the script in the head of the page:

    alert("theImages[whichImage]");

And it gave nothing...?

Comment: No, print just the variable, like this: alert(theImages[whichImage]); you should see an alert with the path of an image, otherwise it means that the function is not called.

Comment: And it must be placed inside the showImage() function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, jquery is not needed in your code.
¿What is the purpose of var j?

Probably you are running showImage() in Header so you can't see the picture.
Try this:

```
   function showImage(){
      var selectedImage = preBuffer[whichImage];
      selectedImage.alt = "Se vores hingste!";
      // Using appendChild instead of document.write
      document.body.appendChild(selectedImage);
   };
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I thought that was necessary whenever i used JavaScript now a days... But i haven't used JS for years...
I have no idea what "var j = 0" means... I found it in a working script, where i just added and changed the last bit of the code. The "original" script was shorter and contained no more j-variabels than this code...


I use that script in the body-section of the page to call the images. That JS is located inside a div.